# All ports on pi are filtered

Tags: wifi, ssh

I have been trying to get ssh working on my raspberry pi. I have a good WiFi connection and everything works fine except that when I do an nmap scan for it, it shows nothing, so I used -Pn and it says that all 1000 ports are filtered. I know that this means that there is a firewall or something dropping the requests, but I didn't setup a firewall or change anything except turning ssh on. Could it be something with my WiFi adapter (RT5370 chipset) or something else?

Comment: Does your network work? Have you enabled ssh? Have you tried to ssh in?

Comment: could it be your wifi access point?

Comment: On the RasPi: what does you the command `systemctl status ssh.service` give? Does it show it's enabled?

Comment: Yes, ssh is enabled but doesn't let me in, and I don't think it could be my WiFi access point because ssh has worked on other devices before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it decided to work. I don't know what the problem was before, but after the IP changed, because I wasn't using a static IP, it works fine. I would still be happy to know why though, if any one has any idea.

Comment: I changed to static IP for the wlan0 interface but it still doesn't work. Same problem as you, on a newly bought RasPi 4 with Raspian Desktop.